# $ not matching position immediately before a newline that is the last character

Tags: php, regex

$ is not matching a position immediately before a newline that is the last character.

Ideally /1...$/ should match but match happens with the pattern /1....$/ which seems to be wrong.

What could be the reason?

[PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) also says A dollar character ($) is an assertion which is TRUE only if the current matching point is at the end of the subject string, or immediately before a newline character that is the last character in the string (by default).

```
$subject = 'abc#
123#
';
$pattern = '/1...$/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$matches); // no match
```

**Update:**
I suspect extra dot due to \r\n format of newline.
I did following experiment and see some hint.

```
$pattern = '/1...(.)$/';

echo bin2hex($matches[1]); // 28
```

28 seems to be equal to \r (CR) so basically $ is matching before \n not before \r\n, that may be the reason of my problem.

[image]

Image after non printable character turn on

Comment: If that's indeed the case, don't hesitate to make your edit an answer instead, and accept it!  The given answer isn't truly an answer, and yours may save someone time in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot acheong, i was actually transferring window php file to linux system where php was installed and caused this issue due to \r\n and \n difference. I created new file on linux system only and everything worked fine /1...$/ matches correctly. Thanks again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was due to different newline representation of window file and linux file

Why this issue:

- I created php file in window and transferred to linux where PHP was installed.
- Windows uses \r\n to represent newline and linux \n ==> that's why initially it was taking extra dot to match.

Below experiment confirmed the same:

```
$subject = 'abc#
123#
';
$pattern = '/1...(.)$/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$matches);
echo bin2hex($matches[1]); // 28 
// 28 is equivalent of \r or CR(carriage return)
```

Created new file in linux system and /1...$/ catches the match :)

I hope this will save someone's time if stuck with same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is multi-line. By default regex won't do multi-line. You have to add the `m` modifier for this to happen.

For example:

```
/1...$/m
```

Comment: i am trying to match $ with single line mode only. Default behavior is to match position before newline char if that is the last character of the string. What is the reference of multiline mode here?

Comment: I don't believe this answer is valid. By default regex won't do multi-line, but Praveen is asking about the behavior described in PHP's documentation: "[...] or immediately before a newline character that is last character in the string." Unfortunately I cannot test this from my current machine, but Praveen's code seems like it _should_ produce a match.

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck on this issue for two days. I did a lot of testing to find any logic that lies behind this because it all depends on where your data comes from (internal and controlled vs. external and uncontrolled). In my case it was input field (`<textarea>`) on my website available from various browsers (and various OS-es) and there were no such problems in JavaScript with pattern testing/matching/checking. Here is a hint for those of you who are trying to fight off (or work around at least) the problem of matching a pattern correctly at the end ($) of any line in multiple lines mode (/m).

```
<?php 
// Various OS-es have various end line (a.k.a line break) chars:
// - Windows uses CR+LF (\r\n);
// - Linux LF (\n);
// - OSX CR (\r).
// And that's why single dollar meta assertion ($) sometimes fails with multiline modifier (/m) mode - possible bug in PHP 5.3.8 or just a "feature"(?).
$str="ABC ABC\n\n123 123\r\ndef def\rnop nop\r\n890 890\nQRS QRS\r\r~-_ ~-_";
//          C          3                   p          0                   _
$pat1='/\w$/mi';    // This works excellent in JavaScript (Firefox 7.0.1+)
$pat2='/\w\r?$/mi'; // Slightly better
$pat3='/\w\R?$/mi'; // Somehow disappointing according to php.net and pcre.org when used improperly
$pat4='/\w(?=\R)/i';    // Much better with allowed lookahead assertion (just to detect without capture) without multiline (/m) mode; note that with alternative for end of string ((?=\R|$)) it would grab all 7 elements as expected
$pat5='/\w\v?$/mi';
$pat6='/(*ANYCRLF)\w$/mi';  // Excellent but undocumented on php.net at the moment (described on pcre.org and en.wikipedia.org)
$n=preg_match_all($pat1, $str, $m1);
$o=preg_match_all($pat2, $str, $m2);
$p=preg_match_all($pat3, $str, $m3);
$r=preg_match_all($pat4, $str, $m4);
$s=preg_match_all($pat5, $str, $m5);
$t=preg_match_all($pat6, $str, $m6);
echo $str."\n1 !!! $pat1 ($n): ".print_r($m1[0], true)
    ."\n2 !!! $pat2 ($o): ".print_r($m2[0], true)
    ."\n3 !!! $pat3 ($p): ".print_r($m3[0], true)
    ."\n4 !!! $pat4 ($r): ".print_r($m4[0], true)
    ."\n5 !!! $pat5 ($s): ".print_r($m5[0], true)
    ."\n6 !!! $pat6 ($t): ".print_r($m6[0], true);
// Note the difference among the three very helpful escape sequences in $pat2 (\r), $pat3 and $pat4 (\R), $pat5 (\v) and altered newline option in $pat6 ((*ANYCRLF)) - for some applications at least.

/* The code above results in the following output:
ABC ABC

123 123
def def
nop nop
890 890
QRS QRS

~-_ ~-_
1 !!! /\w$/mi (3): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 0
    [2] => _
)

2 !!! /\w\r?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

3 !!! /\w\R?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C

    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

4 !!! /\w(?=\R)/i (6): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => f
    [3] => p
    [4] => 0
    [5] => S
)

5 !!! /\w\v?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C

    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

6 !!! /(*ANYCRLF)\w$/mi (7): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => f
    [3] => p
    [4] => 0
    [5] => S
    [6] => _
)
 */
?>
```

Unfortunately, I haven't got any access to a server with the latest PHP version - my local PHP is 5.3.8 and my public host's PHP is version 5.2.17.